# Постепенная загрузка recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как вывести 50 элементов в `recyclerview`, а потом когда я прокрутил к 50, загрузились ещё 50?

Comment: https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поделюсь шаблоном

```
public class LoadMoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
{
    static final int ITEM = 0;
    static final int LOAD_MORE = 1;

    private AdapterListener listener;
    private boolean loading;
    private int itemLayout, loadMoreLayout;

    public class ItemHolder 
    extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
    {
        ItemHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            //...
        }

        void bind(int position)
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    public class LoadMoreHolder 
    extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
    implements OnClickListener
    {
        Button load;
        ProgressBar pb;

        LoadMoreHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            load = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.load_more);
            pb = (ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadmore_pb);
            load.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        void bind()
        {
            load.setVisibility(loading ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            loading = true;
            load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listener.loadMore();
        }
    }

    LoadMoreAdapter(int itemLayout, int loadMoreLayout){
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
        this.loadMoreLayout = loadMoreLayout;
    }

    void setOnAdapterListener(AdapterListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int itemType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        if (itemType == ITEM)
        {
            View v = inflater.inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
            return new ItemHolder(v);
        }
        else
        {
            View v = inflater.inflate(loadMoreLayout, parent, false);
            return new LoadMoreHolder(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == ITEM)
        {
            ((ItemHolder)holder).bind(position);
        }
        else
        {
            ((LoadMoreHolder)holder).bind();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if (position == getPostCount())
        {
            return LOAD_MORE;
        }
        return ITEM;
    }

    public int getPostCount()
    {
        //изменить
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        int postCount = getPostCount();
        if (postCount == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return getPostCount() + 1;
    }

    //вызвать по окончании подгрузки
    void loadingEnd()
    {
        loading = false;
    }

    public interface AdapterListener
    {
        void loadMore();
    }
}
```

Можно переделать на свой лад, если вам нужна автоподгрузка списка, то можете убрать кнопку и перенести код ее слушателя в метод `bind` второго холдера. Например,

```
 public class LoadMoreHolder 
extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
{
    ProgressBar pb;

    LoadMoreHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        pb = (ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadmore_pb);
    }

    void bind()
    {
        if(! loading){
            loading = true;
            listener.loadMore();
        }
    }
}
```